# Вывод данных за период

Tags: select, mysql

Как сделать отбор за текущий месяц, текущую неделю, прошлую неделю и прошлый месяц?

В таблице orders у меня внесены данные в колонке date - 1413118559.8952 (к примеру), таких записей много. :)

Побегав по просторам Интернета, слепил запрос:

```
Select SUM(price) FROM orders WHERE MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(NOW());
```

затем такой:

```
Select SUM(price) FROM orders WHERE date > LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND date < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Запросы-то работают, но выдают нулевой результат, нуждаюсь в помощи.

В каком виде записываются в бд данные в колонку "date", неизвестно, так как код зашифрован, а мне нужно сделать считалку дохода. :)

Comment: Дата ведь хранится в Unix формате?

Comment: этого я не знаю, так какой код запроса добавления туда зашифрован... Единственное что могу сказать  : date varchar(255) utf8_general_ci

Comment: С точки зрения быстродействия лучше всего будет рассчитывать даты начала и конца периода и передавать их в запрос (построитель запроса) и использовать простое сравнение дат, без использования функций.

Comment: Это то понятно, но мне в начале банально нужно узнать как вообще "правильно" вывести и получить "правильный и нужный" мне результат. А пока - Null ...

Comment: Действительно да, работает. :) Огромное вам спасибо Bastian. ^_^

Comment: @DarkAngel232 я рад.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее, должно быть как-то вот так:

```
select count(*) from `orders` where `date` > unix_timestamp(date_sub(current_date, interval 1 month))
```